# Need to add custom button to iphone default browser

Tags: iphone, browser, button, safari

I need to add custom button in iphone browser (i.e., safari). 
And i need perform my functionality using safari browser, that happens by default through web services. 
Before that i need to add a custom button to start that functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Plz help me - is it possible to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. You'll have to create your own browser.

Comment: Thanx mackross so apple guys has not given a chance to customize iphone safari browser.

Comment: Nope, you can't change safari. Your best bet is a bookmarklet in javascript.

http://www.contentious.com/2009/03/14/safari-iphone-bookmarklets-clunky-setup-but-very-useful/

Comment: But I recently heard some guys had implemented this functionality

Comment: Not possible in 4.2. without jailbreaking